# React onClick state is not toggling back

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a menubar using React JS. On clicking a menu item, respective megamenu should open. On clicking outside of the megamenu, it should close itself. I have made upto this by toggling the state of the megamenu. But I also want to close the megamenu, when the menu-item is clicked second-time(i.e. toggle close and open of megamenu by clicking menu-item). I am stuck here, on clicking the menu-item second time, the state is not toggling back.

```
class Menubar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleOutsideClick = this.handleOutsideClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked});
  }

  handleOutsideClick(){
    if (this.refs.megaMenu.contains(event.target)) {
      } else {
        this.setState({
          clicked: false
        });
      }
   }

   render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="menu-bar">
          {/* Menu*/}
          <div className="menu-bar-item">
            <a className="menu-bar-link" href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>Points</a>
            <div className={"mega-menu"+" "+this.state.clicked} ref="megaMenu">
              <div className="mega-menu-content">
                <p>Points Menu</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Menubar />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/sivadass/pen/qNvPzE?editors=0110)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move `ref="megaMenu"` so it includes button as well, otherwise when you click on button `handleOutsideClick` is also triggered and you flip `this.state.clicked` twice. Also, you forgot to pass `event` in `handleOutsideClick` handler.

```
class Menubar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleOutsideClick = this.handleOutsideClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked});
  }

  handleOutsideClick(event) {
    if (!this.menu.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({
        clicked: false
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="menu-bar">

          {/* Menu*/}
          <div className="menu-bar-item" ref={el => this.menu = el}>
            <a className="menu-bar-link" href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>Points</a>
            <div className={"mega-menu" + " " + this.state.clicked}>
              <div className="mega-menu-content">
                <p>Points Menu</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Menubar />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

I've fixed your [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxmdEb)

Also, consider using callback refs like `ref={el => this.menu = el}`
It's a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you explaining my mistakes with your answer :)